# Return an array of objects to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with a simple example below.

I simply would like to create a list of MyImage objects, fill the name, return to the view and display all of them.

My object

```
class MyImage
   def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end
    def name= name
      @name = name
    end
end
```

My Controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @arr ||= Array.new
      @arr.push(MyImage.new('Image1'))
      @arr.push(MyImage.new('Image2'))
   end
end
```

My View

```
<ul>
   <% @arr.each do |t| %>
      <li><%= t.name %></li>
   <% end %>
</ul>
```

The error i get is

```
undefined method `name' for #<MyImage:0x86fca90 @name="Image1">
```

simply want to create an array of objects and display them in the view, and able to access properties of my objects inside my collection.

This is my first ruby attempt so if I am doing something totally not right please point it out as well.

Comment: Have you tried to debug what is present in @arr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way, add getter for name

```
def name
  @name
end
```

You also may user attr_acessor instead writing `def name=` and `def name`

Comment: It is true that you could add an explicit getter to fix the problem, but I wouldn't recommend suggesting it because someone might do it. :)  It dilutes the meaningfulness of the code, since there's a lot of unnecessary verbosity (not that much with 1, but with n quite a bit).  You did mention attr_accessor, and that, I think, is the real answer.

Comment: @KeithBennett, I agree with You  it's not ruby way, but know about different way I think helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a setter for `name` but not a getter.

You can fix this by adding this line to your class definition:

```
attr_reader :name
```

Even better, remove the explicit setter definition entirely, replacing it with a call to `attr_accessor`:

```
class MyImage

  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
end
```

You can simplify this even further using `Struct` to create the class:

```
MyImage = Struct.new(:name)
```